# ScalaTest option not available under "Run As" Menu in Scala IDE

Tags: eclipse, scalatest, scala-ide

I have recently switched computers and am trying to get ScalaTest to run in my ScalaIDE again.

When I right click on the file in the project explorer, or when I right click on the code in the editor, I can see the "Run As" option in the drop down menu, but the only option available is "Run Configurations."

I can create my own run configuration manually, and run the test just fine, and then have a run configuration that I can run from the Run icon in the toolbar, but I don't what to have to create one of these for each tests.

Here is what I have so far, and would be grateful if anybody could provide any additional ideas:

1. Verified that ScalaTest library is being added to the project via SBT.
2. Verified that the Plugin is indeed installed (and re-installed multiple times)
3. Verified that I can run the tests from command line, in addition to my manually configuration in Eclipse.
4. Ran eclipse with -clean command
5. Tried running eclipse as root, and re-installing plugin while running as root.
6. Tried giving all access to all directories in Eclipse.app directory
7. Compared my setup to a co-worker who also recently set up his computer with the same image, and should have very similar versions of Scala, ScalaIDE, and ScalaTest plugin.
8. Created a new workspace and reimported my projects into that workspace.
9. cleared ivy cache and rebuild eclipse project.

My system:

OSX: Yosemite 10.10.5

Scala: 2.11.6

JRE: 1.8.0

ScalaIDE: 4.1.1-vfinal-20150727-1320-Typesafe

ScalaTest Plugin:  2.9.3.v-4-2_11-201509031342-a29ebef

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This morning there was an updated ScalaTest Plugin:

2.9.3.v-4-2_11-201509221346-a29ebef

After updating, everything works fine!

I'll leave this here, as I'm thinking that the steps I took in my question seem to encompass most of the recommended steps that I have seen from various other StackOverflow errors.